snotel_download function from the snotelr package fails to download snotel data
I have been using the snotelr package for many years to download snotel data using snotel_download() and never had any issues. However, when I ran it today, I received an error message:
library(snotelr)
df <- snotel_download(site_id = c(429,1287), internal = TRUE)

issues

Error in strsplit(df$site_name, "\(") : non-character argument

On R 4.3.3, in an attempt to fix the issue, I downloaded the newest version of the snotelr package but that did not fix the problem.

Hi, maybe raise it as an issue here: https://github.com/bluegreen-labs/snotelr/issues

On
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.3

running
remotes::install_github("bluegreen-labs/snotelr", build_vignettes = TRUE)
library("snotelr")
df <- snotelr::snotel_download(site_id = c(429,1287), internal = TRUE)

works. Under loaded via a namespace (and not attached): at sessionInfo()we find snotelr_1.4. Calling snotelr::snotel_download(... instead of snotel_download(... seems important.

Thanks for your response. It sounds like the issue has been fixed. See https://github.com/bluegreen-labs/snotelr
